# How to accept the patch choice by default?

Tags: fish

I started to use `fish` and while it looks very good there is one functionality I would like to customize. Starting from a bare prompt, if I type for instance `cd` I get

[image]

`/etc/firehol` was automatically suggested but if I want to accept this choice I have to type `End` to move the cursor at the end, then `Enter`.

**Is there a way to directly use `Enter`**, i.e. accept the choice as it is displayed?

The fact that I have a command which is displayed but which does not run as it is somehow disturbing for me (probably due to what i am used to with `bash`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's more bindings to accept suggestions - all (IIRC) bindings that move the cursor will accept at least part of it.

One is Ctrl-F ("forward-char"), which will accept all of it.

If you really want to have one binding to accept and then execute, you can bind "accept-autosuggestion" and "execute", i.e. `bind \cs 'commandline -f accept-autosuggestion execute'` to bind it to Ctrl-S.

Comment: Thank you. Would there be a reason for not using `bind \n 'commandline -f accept-autosuggestion execute'` (which seems to work fine after a quick test)?

Comment: Well, what if you want to execute just what you have, without the suggestion? You'd want to add a new binding for that. I don't think the binding itself should cause issues.

Comment: I guess it is a matter of usage. I usually get back to commands I used, or use new ones. I rarely edit one, or rather use a pieces, as it is the default in fish. So I press a few page ups, or start to type, and then accept what I see. Anyway - thank you for the solution!

Comment: FYI, in the next fish release (2.3.0) or if you build fish from git head newline (\n) and carriage-return (\r) are distinct. Which is to say pressing [Enter], which normally sends \r, will no longer be automatically mapped to \n. So you'll want to bind \r rather than \n (or bind both).